# What is the best structure for code in modules?

Tags: python, class, module, package

I am making a python package for bioinformatics, wherein I have created a module. Since I am not adept with the practices used to develop modules so I am confused how to make them. I want to achieve import statements like

```
import Rosa

phenotype = Rosa.Punnet.progeny('AABbCCDd','AaBbccDD',show = 'phenotype')
```

This works but behind the scenes

```
class Punnet:

 def progeny(genotype1,genotype2,show = 'genotype'):
    g1 = re.findall('..',genotype1)
    g2 = re.findall('..',genotype2)
    g1 = [list(i) for i in g1]
    g2 = [list(i) for i in g2]
    gametes1 = [list(i) for i in itertools.product(*g1)]
    gametes2 = [list(i) for i in itertools.product(*g2)]
    mate = [list(i) for i in itertools.product(gametes1,gametes2)]
    if show == 'genotype':
        progeny = []
        for i1 in mate:
            alleles = list(zip(i1[0],i1[1]))
            offspring = ''
            for i2 in alleles:
                allele = list(i2)
                allele.sort()
                allele = ''.join(allele)
                offspring += allele
            progeny.append(offspring)
        unique,counts = np.unique(progeny,return_counts = True)
        progeny = dict(zip(unique,counts))
    elif show == 'phenotype':
        progeny = []
        for i1 in mate:
            alleles = list(zip(i1[0],i1[1]))
            offspring = ''
            for i2 in alleles:
                allele = list(i2)
                allele.sort()
                trait = allele[0]
                offspring += trait
            progeny.append(offspring)
        unique,counts = np.unique(progeny,return_counts = True)
        progeny = dict(zip(unique,counts))
    return progeny
```

`progeny` actually is a function defined inside class `Punnet` in the module's code. I confused myself with static methods and class methods etc. This doesn't seem the right way to structure the package.

What is the correct/better way to make the package and why is my code working? Given that I am not making an instance of class `Punnet`, I just call the function via `Rosa.Punnet.progeny()`

Comment: btw you can (and should) make that method a `@staticmethod` since it doesn't use class or instance

Comment: if you don't need the class then just define a function, and then you could use it as `phenotype = Rosa.progeny(...)`, you don't necessarily need a class. To import the module you basically need to use a relative path from the current working directory (unless you use a package) to navigate to the file. In the example above both files simply need to be in the same directory (and the directory should be the current working one)

Comment: I am making multiple sub-packages, Rosa is the main and then Punnet, Sequence, Blast ... multiple packages are inside it, I am looking for an answer describing the directory structure for such a package that allows me to write import statements like I mentioned.

Comment: `Punnet` is not a _sub-package_, it is a class, and `Rosa` is the module presumably which contains that class. Package is just a directory that contains an `__init__.py` file and the directory name is the package name, packaged can contain other packages or modules. And I already described the simplest structure: have both modules in the same folder that is also the working directory, then you can import `Rosa` module and use its classes, but the classes seem useless because you don't actually do anything with them